# Gnome-Tweaks capslock setting doesn't work on external keyboard

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I use gnome-tweaks to remap my caps-lock key as escape. This has worked fine for a long time, but since updating the OS yesterday the remapping doesn't apply if I plug in my USB keyboard after I set it.

The machine:

```
Ubuntu 20.04
~$ echo "$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP"
ubuntu:GNOME
GNOME Tweaks 3.34.0
GNOME Shell 3.36.4 (ubuntu mode)
GTK 3.24.20
```

Specific symptoms:

I noticed my "escape" key wasn't working right today, so I checked in Tweaks: said it was properly remapped. I flicked it back and forth, after which it was working.

Since then, the caps-lock key on the laptop's built-in keyboard seems to reliably work as ESC, but if I un-plug and plug-back-in my external keyboard its caps-lock is caps-lock until I go back into Tweaks and toggle the setting.

Note that the setting never changes in Tweaks, it just doesn't apply to the external keyboard until I change it to something else and back again.